# Create bluetooth device

Tags: drivers, keyboard, bluetooth, ps3

Can I use my bluetooth enabled laptop to create bluetooth keyboards or other devices?
ps: I would like to use my laptop keyboard on my PS3

Comment: You'd need a Bluetooth stack that does that and if I remember correctly, none of the stacks for PCs do that.

Comment: This is weird. Just a few days ago, I passed by a computer store and they had keyboards with Bluetooth. Their discription said they were connectable with smartphones and game consoles... If you think this is something for you, ask me more about it..

Comment: Karel, I want to avoid to buy a bluetooth keyboard as my laptop has bluetooth.